# Best query to get multiple columns from a GroupBy of two JOIN-ed tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a SQL query to get multiple columns from a joined table, and I've seen there are two approaches, either to have multiple columns in the GROUPBY, or use an aggregator on the results, but I'm not sure which of these is the best approach, or if there is a performance benefit to either?

As an example, I have user and purchases tables:

`dbo.[User]`

| Id (PK) | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Name1 |
| 2 | Name2 |

`dbo.Purchases`

| Id (PK) | UserId (FK) | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 | 5 |

I would like to get the UserId, Name and total quantity for all the users, which I think can be done in two ways:

**Approach A:**

```
SELECT u.Id, u.[Name], SUM(p.Quantity) as Quantity
FROM dbo.[User] u
LEFT JOIN dbo.Purchases p ON p.UserId = u.Id
GROUP BY u.Id, u.[Name]
```

**Approach B:**

```
SELECT u.Id, MAX(u.[Name]), SUM(p.Quantity) as Quantity
FROM dbo.[User] u
LEFT JOIN dbo.Purchases p ON p.UserId = u.Id
GROUP BY u.Id
```

Both of these seem strange to me though, because it should be clear from `User.Id` being a primary key that if I am grouping by `User.Id` then any other fields from `[User]` must have a unique value, so I'm confused why something like the following doesn't work:

```
--- INCORRECT ---
SELECT u.Id, u.[Name], SUM(p.Quantity) as Quantity
FROM dbo.[User] u
LEFT JOIN dbo.Purchases p ON p.UserId = u.Id
GROUP BY u.Id
```

Which approach (A) or (B) - or a different approach - am I best to use?

Comment: Why not race your horses and find out? You're in the best position to do so.

Comment: As for that you think it "strange", the requirements of aggregation is that any expressions *not* in the `GROUP BY` *must* be aggregated. It doesn't matter if the value is guaranteed to be unique or not; you *must* be explicit. The data engine isn't going to check, as part of compiling the query, that the value of `ID` is unique and therefore `Name` too must be unique for that value of `ID`; such actions could very likely be detrimental to the compilation time of the query, as such checks are performed.

Comment: Someone mentioned that postgre can handle these kind of relations so you don't have to group by every field. Mysql also have similar support. Alas, not sql server for now

Comment: Isn't MySQL's "solution" to just apply an arbitrary aggregate function to non-grouped columns, @siggemannen , and in recent versions of MySQL it doesn't do that behaviour by default (any more). I'm pretty sure it's not ANSI/ISO behaviour to allow non-grouped and non-aggregated columns in the `SELECT`.

Comment: @ThomA, i don't remember the details, but you're probably correct, at least the old implementation didn't track the relationship details. And yes, it's probably changed now, but it used to "work" by default

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Combined answer based on the suggestions to run the queries to see how they perform.

Note: *I ran this for my specific example, so the timings and query plan weightings apply to my use-case, but were helpful to me to understand the differences. (Timings are just approximate - they vary by 100-200ms between executions.)*

**Approach A**

```
SELECT uAct.Id, uAct.PrimaryEmail, uAct.LatestActivity FROM
    (SELECT u.Id, u.PrimaryEmail, Max(ta.ActivityTime) as LatestActivity
        FROM dbo.[User] u
        LEFT JOIN dbo.TimedActivity ta ON ta.UserId = u.Id
        GROUP BY u.Id, u.PrimaryEmail) uAct
    WHERE [someFilter])
```

Time: 00:00:00.290

Query Plan:
[image]

**Approach B**

```
SELECT uAct.Id, PrimaryEmail, uAct.LatestActivity FROM
    (SELECT u.Id, MAX(u.PrimaryEmail) as PrimaryEmail, Max(ta.ActivityTime) as LatestActivity
        FROM dbo.[User] u
        LEFT JOIN dbo.TimedActivity ta ON ta.UserId = u.Id
        GROUP BY u.Id) uAct
    WHERE [someFilter])
```

Time: 00:00:00.247

Query Plan:
[image]

**Approach C (suggested by @siggemannen)**

```
SELECT u.Id, u.PrimaryEmail, uAct.LatestActivity FROM
    dbo.[User] u
    LEFT JOIN(
        SELECT MAX(ta.ActivityTime) as LatestActivity
        , UserId
        FROM dbo.TimedActivity ta
        GROUP BY UserId
    ) uAct
    ON uAct.UserId = u.Id
    WHERE [someFilter])
```

Time: 00:00:00.135

Query Plan:
[image]

**Approach D (suggested by @siggemannen)**

```
SELECT u.Id, u.PrimaryEmail, uAct.LatestActivity FROM
    dbo.[User] u
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT MAX(ta.ActivityTime) as LatestActivity
        FROM dbo.TimedActivity ta
        WHERE ta.UserId = u.Id
    ) uAct
    WHERE [someFilter])
```

Time: 00:00:01.707

Query Plan:
[image]

**Conclusion**
Approaches A, B and C seem to have very similar performance and execution. Approach D is much slower for my specific case. I'm supposing is due to creating a whole table inside the query? The key difference is the "Index Spool" taking up 82% of the execution time there.

I don't know much about query plans to identify any key differences in performance between A, B and C. I suppose this is likely to come down to relative sizes of tables - in my case not much difference at all.

Comment: you added a filter, which might complicate things, depending on what you're filtering out (if it's aggregated or user data), it might change the character of the plans. ALso, the grouping of CreatedDate is different between all the queries, which further complicates the comparison. It's importing to compare same things

Comment: Good spot, I adjusted the queries to match - no difference to the timings (which are only approx anyway) or the query plans. For the filters, I included these as I used them to test the 4 query plans, however in each case they happen last (before the SELECT) and took 0% relative time, so they don't seem to have an overall effect.

Comment: Having subqueries in a FROM clause is a common practive, but not a good one, mainly for readibility and maintainability. And moreover, I can't see the need to have a subquery in the A & B approaches.

Comment: Can you post a suggestion without the subqueries?

Answer (score 1):

Another way which might be more natural is the following:

```sql
SELECT u.Id, u.[Name], totalQuantity
FROM dbo.[User] u
LEFT JOIN (
   select  SUM(p.Quantity) as TotalQuantity
   , UserId
   FROM   dbo.Purchases p 
   GROUP BY UserId
  ) p
ON p.UserId = u.Id
```

This groups purchases separately and then joins them back. There's no performance hit usually since sql server can figure out and LEFT JOIN "through" the User table. Ie, it doesn't materialize whole purchase table unnecessarily.

Similar to this is the OUTER APPLY (cross apply should give same results in this case too i think) approach:

```sql
SELECT u.Id, u.[Name], totalQuantity
FROM dbo.[User] u
OUTER APPLY (
   select  SUM(p.Quantity) as TotalQuantity
   FROM   dbo.Purchases p 
   WHERE p.UserId = u.Id
  ) p
```

These *should* generate pretty identical plans in most cases, but of course the best is to test it

Comment: Thank you for the alternative approaches too. The consideration I have in mind is if both the `User` and `Purchases` tables may be quite large, and I may only want the final results for a few users (e.g `User.Id < 5`). My concern is whether any of these queries will additionally be performing a GROUP/JOIN on very large tables, or if this is optimised in all of the possible approaches?

Comment: As i wrote, SQL Server will *usually* handle it correctly regardless of sizes of the underlying tables. But yes, it can mess up, but that can happen with any of the queries. The only way to force it is by using LOOP JOINs and stuff, but it's for advanced use only. Why not try those queries out on your data and see how it behaves. You should be able to compare the query plans for various scenarios

Answer (score 1):

Try with the below code to get the desired result set.

```
Create table [user]
(
ID int,
[Name] varchar(20)
)
insert into [user]
Select 1, 'Name1'
union all 
Select 2, 'Name2'

Create table [Purchases]
(
ID int,
userID int,
Quantity int
)
insert into [Purchases]
Select 1,1, 2
union all 
Select 2,1,3
Union all 
Select 3,2,5

--Select Query
Select p.userID, u.[Name], SUM(p.Quantity) AS TotalQuantity
from purchases p
JOIN [user] u
on p.userid = u.id
GROUP BY p.userid,u.Name

OUTPUT:
userID  Name    TotalQuantity
-------------------------
1       Name1       5
2       Name2       5
```

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between approach A and approach B is that there is no need to include the name column under the GROUP BY section as you are commanding the MAX value for name under approach B.

I have just attempted to replicate your results (using slightly different notation) and either approach can work.

**Approach A**

`select t1.id, t1.name, sum(t2.quantity) from table1 as t1 inner join table2 as t2 on t1.id=t2.id group by t1.id, t1.name order by t1.id;`

[image: table]

**Approach B**

`select t1.id, max(t1.name) as name, sum(t2.quantity) from table1 as t1 inner join table2 as t2 on t1.id=t2.id group by t1.id order by t1.id;`

[image: approach b]

For Approach B, the only change I would make is to specify `max(t1.name) as name`, otherwise the column that displays the name will be called *max* instead of name.